# How to get contours as image with opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I want to get contours from image and display only filled contours on black image.

My code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sample.jpeg')
black_img = np.zeros(img.shape)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,tresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(black_img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
plt.imshow(black_img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is sample.jpeg

doesn't give me the expected output, but black img.

How can I do this?

Comment: I normally hate just posting links, but this one has your answers. In order to answer your question to the fullest would just be a copy-pasta. [PyDoc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do in Python/OpenCV might be:

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sample.jpeg')
black_img = np.zeros(img.shape)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
thresh = 255 - thresh
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
cv2.drawContours(black_img,[contours[0]],0,(0,255,0),-1)
cv2.imwrite('sample_contour.jpg',black_img)
cv2.imshow('result',black_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few problems with

```
cv2.drawContours(img2,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
plt.imshow(black_img)
```

First, where's `img2` coming from? I'd expect that to explode, but it's not the image you're then showing. You could draw over the top of `img` instead, and then show it. Or you could try drawing the contours on `black_img`.

Comment: img2 means black_img sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry. This is programming, which is partly a process of learning what mistakes one tends to make so that they can be guarded against in the future.